# $uibModal reopen same page

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-click on a button to open a modal. When I try to open it, the design open a modal but with the page where I open it. Why is it possible?

```
$scope.EditPlayer = function (gid) {
        var modalIstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: "/Modal/modalUser.html",
            controller: 'UserEditController'
        });
    }
```

I think that my routing create some problem...

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider

            .when('/', { controller: 'MainController', templateUrl: 'Views/home.html' })
            .when('/index', { controller: 'MainController', templateUrl: 'Views/home.html' })
            .when('/index.html', { controller: 'MainController', templateUrl: 'Views/home.html' })

            .when('/userlist', { controller: 'UserListController', templateUrl: 'Views/userlist.html' })
            .when('/useradd', { controller: 'UserAddController', templateUrl: 'Views/useradd.html' })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    })
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Did you try `empty cache and hard reload` ? it looks ok.

Comment: Ofc: I've Disable cache on Chrome and always console open.

Comment: Are you asking why the modal opens on the page where the EditPlayer function was invoked?

Comment: No, I'm askying why the content of the modal is the same as tha page in background. Here an example: https://ibb.co/cYN2g6